# MVC child - parent on the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I'm pretty new to using MVC3 so hopefully the terms I'm using are all correct.

Basically I'm looking for a way (if possible!) to have a parent and child(s) record be added on the same page. I'm able to get the page to display correctly, but I'm unsure how to update the parent model.

In my Create view I have all the fields for the parent, and I'd also like to add the child records to the form as well.

I'm currently using `Html.RenderPartial("CreateChildView")` to display my Create child page within the parent.

I'm also using `Html.RenderPartial("IndexChildView)` to display my child records that have been added.

Where I'm stuck at is how to update the Parent model from the "CreateChildView" from above,
I've tried adding a submit button to the child view but I'm not getting the results I was hoping for.

the equivelent c# code that I'm kind of looking for is:

`ParentObject.ChildObject.Add(new ChildObject)`

and then a way to display this correctly

Thanks in Advance

Comment: it would help if you could post some of the code you are actually using.  By the way i assume are surrounding your view fiedls with an Html.BeginForm(), and you have an Action method in the controller with an [HttpPost] attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place both partials in div with ids. Post data with ajax from "CreateChildView" and update "IndexChildView" with response.